# How to assert "N" exceptions have been thrown in this unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, testng

I've got the following unit test, which works *almost* fine:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = {IllegalArgumentException.class}, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp =
        PasswordValidator.INVALID_PASSWORD)
public void testInvalidPasswordsThrowException() throws Exception {
    for (String invalidPassword: getInvalidPasswords()){
        new LaxPasswordValidator(invalidPassword);
    }
}

private String[] getInvalidPasswords() {
    return new String[] {INVALID_PASSWORD_1, INVALID_PASSWORD_2, INVALID_PASSWORD_3, INVALID_PASSWORD_4,
            INVALID_PASSWORD_5, INVALID_PASSWORD_6, INVALID_PASSWORD_7, INVALID_PASSWORD_8, INVALID_PASSWORD_9,
            INVALID_PASSWORD_10};
}
```

As you can see, it is just asserting that `new LaxPasswordValidator(invalidPassword)` works as expected and throws an exception.

**Problem:** It is just taking `INVALID_PASSWORD_1` into account, so it stops in the first iteration; it launches the exception but does not continue checking the other passwords. How can I make it test them all? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must annotate the method as [@DataProvider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)

```
@DataProvider(name = "invalid-passwords")
public Object[][] getInvalidPasswords() {
    return new String[][]{
        {"INVALID_PASSWORD_1"},
        {"INVALID_PASSWORD_2"},
        {"INVALID_PASSWORD_3"}
    };
}
```

and annotate the `@Test` method to use this dataprovider for the parameters.

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = {IllegalArgumentException.class},
    expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = PasswordValidator.INVALID_PASSWORD,
    dataProvider = "invalid-passwords")
public void testInvalidPasswords(String password) throws Exception {
    new LaxPasswordValidator(password);
}
```